# how to display item selected from searchable dropdown in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, dropdown

I want year to be displayed on selection from dropdown list.

In this, selected item is being shown as alert I want to set text to the search box.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import SearchableDropdown from "react-native-searchable-dropdown";

const years = [
  { id: 1, name: "2021" },
  { id: 2, name: "2020" },
  { id: 3, name: "2019" },
  { id: 4, name: "2018" },
  { id: 5, name: "2017" },
  { id: 6, name: "2016" },
  { id: 7, name: "2015" },
];
export default function Year() {
  console.log("App Executed");
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.headingText}>Select Year</Text>
      <SearchableDropdown
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        // On text change listner on the searchable input
        onItemSelect={(year) => alert(JSON.stringify(year))}
        // onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
        containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
        // suggestion container style
        textInputStyle={{
          // inserted text style
          padding: 12,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#ccc",
          backgroundColor: "#FAF7F6",
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          // single dropdown item style
          padding: 10,
          marginTop: 2,
          backgroundColor: "#FAF9F8",
          borderColor: "#bbb",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
        itemTextStyle={{
          // text style of a single dropdown item
          color: "#222",
        }}
        itemsContainerStyle={{
          // items container style you can pass maxHeight
          // to restrict the items dropdown hieght
          maxHeight: "50%",
        }}
        items={years}
        // mapping of item array
        defaultIndex={"eg:2021"}
        // default selected item index
        placeholder="eg:2021"
        // place holder for the search input
        resetValue={false}
        // reset textInput Value with true and false state
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
  },
  titleText: {
    padding: 8,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  headingText: {
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to use state
here is the solution

```js
const years = [
  { id: 1, name: "2021" },
  { id: 2, name: "2020" },
  { id: 3, name: "2019" },
  { id: 4, name: "2018" },
  { id: 5, name: "2017" },
  { id: 6, name: "2016" },
  { id: 7, name: "2015" },
];
export default function Year() {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState();
  console.log("App Executed");
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SearchableDropdown
        onTextChange={(text) => console.log(text)}
        // On text change listner on the searchable input
        selectedItems={selectedItems}
        onItemSelect={(year) => setSelectedItems(year)}
        // onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
        containerStyle={{ padding: 5 }}
        // suggestion container style
        textInputStyle={{
          // inserted text style
          padding: 12,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#ccc",
          backgroundColor: "#FAF7F6",
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          // single dropdown item style
          padding: 10,
          marginTop: 2,
          backgroundColor: "#FAF9F8",
          borderColor: "#bbb",
          borderWidth: 1,
        }}
        itemTextStyle={{
          // text style of a single dropdown item
          color: "#222",
        }}
        itemsContainerStyle={{
          // items container style you can pass maxHeight
          // to restrict the items dropdown hieght
          maxHeight: "50%",
        }}
        items={years}
        // mapping of item array
        defaultIndex={"eg:2021"}
        // default selected item index
        placeholder="eg:2021"
        // place holder for the search input
        resetValue={false}
        // reset textInput Value with true and false state
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: adding selectedItems={selectedItems} into your options does the job

Answer (score 0):

**I SLOVED THAT BY THIS TRICK WAY:**

```
const getTypeNameById_func = async id => {
    const dataa = await accountsType.find(item => {
      if (item.ID == id) 
      return item.NAME;
    });
    setTextSearchable(dataa.NAME);
  };
```

**AND IN SEARCHABLE DROPDOWN :**

```
 <SearchableDropdown
              items={filterData}
               placeholder={String(**textSearchable**)}
              resetValue={false}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              onTextChange={text => console.log(text)}
              onItemSelect={item => {
                getTypeNameById_func(item.id);
                setAccountType(item.id);
              }}
              defaultIndex={1}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use useState variable and pass that variable in placeholder like:-

```
placeholder={variableName}
```